use webcomponent as replacement for iframe
Since I could not get iframes to work in browsers on ios, I am trying to replace the functionality of the iframe with a webcomponent:
class EmbeddedWebview extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    fetch(this.getAttribute('src'))
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(html => {
        const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'closed' });
        shadow.innerHTML = html;
      });
  }
}
 
window.customElements.define(
  'embedded-webview',
  EmbeddedWebview
);

and then use it in html as follows:
<embedded-webview src="a/b/index.html"></embedded-webview>

This works, except when the site with the embedded-webview tag is loaded a different path, e.g. root (e.g. /index.html) the included content tries to load assets (e.g. css,  etc) from the wrong url.
How can I solve this issue? Is there a way to set the origin of the innerHTML?

Have you checked https://caniuse.com/?search=iframe - it should be possible to use an iframe on IOS.

"...tag is loaded a different path, e.g. root (e.g. /index.html) the included content tries to load assets (e.g. css, etc) from the wrong url." It's probably because you have two different files named index.html located at the two different locations. a/b/ is a different location than /.

Do you get a Content-Security-Policy error?

@AHaworth I know it should. The page you linked also mentioned a but in Apple's iframe implementation. I don't know that my issue is related to that bug, but no matter how I create the iframe, on ios it just shows up as a white rectangle. Everywhere else it works just fine.

@zer00ne No. Details: html with <embedded ... is at /test.html. Included site is at /doc/index.html. It includes at style at styles.css that is located at /doc/styles.css but tries to load from /styles.css which does not exist. iframe handles this correctly, my custom element does not. How can I fix this?  I should tell that the root for index.html is at /doc, but how?

@zer00ne No security error. /doc/index.html loads fine, but since it does not find the styles, the website is not correctly formatted.
